# Send prop with react route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, use-state

I try to send a data called favProduct to Favourites component. When I send the data, I get undefined. How can I send a data when I use react route?

```
const [favProduct, setFavProduct] = useState([1,2,3,4,5]);


  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Home}/>
          <Route path="/men" component={Men} />
          <Route path="/women" component={Women} />
          <Route path="/kids" component={Kids} />
          <Route path="/productBuy" component={ProductBuy} />
          <Route path="/favourites" component={Favourites} />
          <Route path="/cart" component={Cart} />
          <Route path="/checkout" component={Checkout} />
          <Route path="/addproduct" component={AddProduct} />
        </Switch>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want, or need, to send additional props to routed components, use the `Route`'s `render` prop to inject the props ***and*** forward the route props.

Example:

```
<Route
  path="/favourites"
  render={props => <Favourites {...props} favProduct={favProduct} />}
/>
```

Access all the route props as done previously, i.e. `props.location`, `props.history`, etc... and access the new prop that was passed, i.e. `props.favProduct`.

Comment: Thank you very much. it solved the problem.

Comment: @OzanBilgiç please consider accepting this answer to close your question and help future visitors. You can also flag this answer as useful/helpful (+1)

Comment: Yes, I am waiting for 10 minutes to acccept. Stackoverflow doesn't let me to accept any answer before 10 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

If using react-router v6+, in your route, [try this](https://ui.dev/react-router-pass-props-to-components/):

```
<Route path="/favourites" element={<Favourites favProduct={favProduct} />} />
```